# PHP $_SESSION turning from Array to Object

Tags: php, arrays, object, session-variables

My problem is simple to state : my $_SESSION is, after running a really small piece of code, turning from an Array to an Object (and changing values too!)

Just have a look at it, turning from :

```
[_SESSION] => Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )
)
```

to :

```
[_SESSION] => Array
(
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

)
```

And the script executing in between is a simple PDO query, using `$_SESSION['user']['id']` as a parameter to bind.

Mighty gold help me!

**EDIT**: Here is the PDO query i run:

```
function get_relatives_by_id($list_ids){ // $list_ids has been sanitized
    global $co;
    $tr = $co->prepare("SELECT id FROM people WHERE id IN (". $list_ids .") AND id IN (
                            SELECT id_people1 FROM people_relationships WHERE id_people2=:id_connected_user
                        ) ORDER BY id ASC");
    $tr->bindParam(':id_connected_user', $_SESSION['user']['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $tr->execute();
    return $tr->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Following your ideas, i tried retrieving a second column to see if the `$_SESSION` would be modified too, and well it is..

So, making the query look like that : `SELECT id, email FROM..`
Is making the `$_SESSION` look like :

```
[_SESSION] => Array
(
    [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1,
            [email] => lol@lol.lol
        )

)
```

Weird, isn't it ?

**EDIT 3: I just tried to run my project with Wamp and.. no problem here, as expected since the code is right. So i guess i'll have to dig in OVH's servers configuration, and you won't be able to help me here. Anyway, i thank everyone who participated in this Question! Really!**

Comment: Can you put the code that you think to be the cause ?

Comment: Without all the code, it's hard to help. You should add another params to see if they change too.

Comment: I think you might be best off using an IDE with xdebug, set a watch on SESSION or the [user] entry, and step through your code to find out when/where that happens. Unlikely it's a PHP issue.

Comment: You're binding a component of _SESSION directly? Probably PDO doing it, then, as a side effect of the binding. Use an intermediate temporary variable instead, perhaps.

Comment: Are you binding value or binding parameter? As binding parameters might hold some weird behavior (so I hear). Please add the code so that we can help you.

Comment: I added the query. I'm binding the $_SESSION directly, yes. I'm trying with an intermediate var, brb.

Comment: Well i added a `$id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];`, and used `bindParam()` with `$id`, but that doesn't solve anything :/

Answer (score 1):

you can force it to be array with

```
$_SESSION['user'] = (array) 'yourdata';
```

Comment: Well yes, but i'd like to understand why it's changing itself like that. And the problem is that values change too! (From 2 to 1 in my example)

Comment: @Pioul: Once you bind a variable in PDO, it acts like a reference and stays bound to whatever comes out of PDO. If you're retrieving multiple rows, then whatever's in that session var will be the LAST thing to come out of PDO.

Comment: @Pioul: you'll have to search throught your code. You're forcing it/changing it somewhere

Comment: @genesis: "the script executing in between is a simple PDO query"

Comment: @Marc I tried to solve that with a `$id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];` and then using `$id` with `bindParam`, but it's still not working :/

Comment: @Marc But yeah you're right, i mean the last id retrieved by my request is 1, and `$_SESSION['user']['id']` now contains 1 instead of 2. But why is it still happening when i'm not binding the `$_SESSION`anymore ? o.O

Comment: @pioul: What you've shown above, plus now using the intermediate $id var should mean that _SESSION isn't involved with PDO anymore, so must be something else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) as it seems that PDO will modify the reference you are passing in to BindParam even though it should only read it.

From [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> ```
> bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
> ```
>
> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was use to prepare the statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.
>
> Most parameters are input parameters, that is, parameters that are used in a read-only fashion to build up the query. Some drivers support the invocation of stored procedures that return data as output parameters, and some also as input/output parameters that both send in data and are updated to receive it.

Comment: That would have been a wonderful trick, but i just replaced every `bindParam` with `bindValue`, and still no change.

Comment: It probably doesn't fit with the function caller, but what happens when you change the value in `fetchAll()`?

Comment: Hahaha when i do that, the last retrieved row is still inserted in my `$_SESSION`, but is an Array if im using `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, and same shit for others, even if i call `fetchAll()` without anything inside.. That bug is SOOOOO much fun!

Comment: Wow...ya. I guess try passing the `user_id` into the function (removes the dependency on a global variable which is good practice for unit testing) or copying the value into another variable.

Comment: Tried that, and it's still overwriting `$_SESSION`.. The strange fact is that i must have about 60 other queries like this one, using `$_SESSION`the exact same way, and working more than fine..